# How to make an instance of a class delete itself from an array list

Tags: java, arraylist

In java, I would like to have an instance of a class in an array list delete itself after its main loop is done, not just a random one, but the instance itself. How would I do that?

Comment: What's the motivation? What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

The remove method in java's List class removes the exact object you insert into it as determined by the '==' operator.

Something like this might work for you:

```
public interface IDeleteListener<T> {
    void delete(SelfDeleteItem<T> item);
}

public class SelfDeleteItem<T> {
    IDeleteListener<T> listener;
    T item;

    public SelfDeleteItem(T item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public void fireDelete() {
        listener.delete(this);
    }
            public void setDeleteListener(IDeleteListener<T> listener){
                this.listener = listener;
            }
}

public class DeleteList<T> {
    private List<SelfDeleteItem<T>> items;
    IDeleteListener<T> deleteListener;

    public DeleteList() {
        this.items = new ArrayList<SelfDeleteItem<T>>();
        this.deleteListener = new IDeleteListener<T>() {
            public void delete(SelfDeleteItem<T> item) {
                items.remove(item);
            }
        };
    }

    public SelfDeleteItem<T> add(T item) {
                    SelfDeleteItem<T> test= new SelfDeleteItem<T>(item);
                    test.setDeleteListener(this.deleteListener);
        this.items.add(test);
    }
}
```

An example:

```
DeleteList<String> list= //...
SelfDeleteItem<String> deleteItem = list.add("test");
deleteItem.fireDelete();
```

The way this code works, is each time an instance of some value is added to DeleteList, it is placed in a wrapper, SelfDeleteItem.  Self delete item has a listener that it notifies when it wants to be deleted.  DeleteList registers itself as a listener for when SelfDeleteItem wants to be deleted, and proceeds to delete SelfDeleteItem in that case.

This decouples the list from the item via a listener, and accomplishes your goal of allowing an item to delete itself.

As for uses, this approach is useful for audio and network buffer caches.  Being able to cache or uncache an object without creating a dependency is desireable.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you would like to remove a particular instance of an Object that you have added to an ArrayList. If that is the case, at the end of the main method, make a call to:

```
public boolean remove(Object o)
```

a [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) of ArrayList.

Here is how the method works. Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present. If the list does not contain the element, it is unchanged. More formally, removes the element with the lowest index `i` such that `(o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))` (if such an element exists). Returns `true` if this list contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this list changed as a result of the call).

Comment: You don't mention _how_ `remove` works. You don't explain how the `List` decides which `Object` is the same `o` in the `List`. I think you need that for a full answer.

Comment: I didn't feel I needed to copy and paste what the hyperlink says exactly. I can though

Comment: There is a [good question on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) on this topic.

Comment: I do see the benefit now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The class instance has to know it is in the list.  Presumably the class would have a method that's called when when the instance is added to the list.  Then when the instance wants to remove itself from the list it does so using the list's "remove" method, something like: "mainList.remove( this );".

Generally you'd want to handle adding and removing the list from outside the class; a class instance should not know or care whether it's in the list.   On the other hand, sometimes a class does have to look out for itself and disentangle itself from lists and other connections.

Comment: Good answer Ralph. My answer does what you suggest without creating a dependency on any data structure.